# Connecting two functions - Copy slides, grab new slide ID, and put ID in next function

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created two scripts. One to make a copy of an existing slide deck and one to automate filling in data throughout the slide deck.

My challenge is pulling the ID of the new copy for the second function without manually opening it up, copying it, and pasting it.

This works to make a copy.

```
function createCopyUsingDriveApp() {
 // The Id of the presentation to copy
 var templateId = "my slide template ID";

 // Create a copy of the presentation using DriveApp
 var template = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId);
 var fileName = template.getName();
 var copy = template.makeCopy();
copy.setName("Copy of " + fileName);
}
```

And this works when i manually grab the new sheets ID.

```
function automateReport() {
  
  var Presentation_ID = "target sheets ID"

  var Presentation = SlidesApp.openById(Presentation_ID) ;
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange().getValues();

  values.forEach(function(row){
    var templateVariable= row[4]
    var templateValue= row[3];
    Presentation.replaceAllText(templateVariable,templateValue) ;
  });
}
```

How can I connect the two?

Answer (score 0):

```
function createCopyUsingDriveApp(tid) {
  var template = DriveApp.getFileById(tid);
  var fileName = template.getName();
  var copy = template.makeCopy();
  copy.setName("Copy of " + fileName);
  return copy.getId();
}

function automateReport(pid) {
  var Presentation = SlidesApp.openById(pid);
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange().getValues();
  values.forEach(function (row) {
    var templateVariable = row[4]
    var templateValue = row[3];
    Presentation.replaceAllText(templateVariable, templateValue);
  });
}

automateReport(createCopyUsingDriveApp(tid))
```

Comment: I see you added the return copy.getID();. I can I pass that through to the next function? Tid is just a placeholder for the sheet to be copied, right? I don't understand how to pass that returned ID through the next function in place of pid.

Comment: There are a bunch of tutorials in here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript